# Not receiving all emails sent to my Google Apps account (via Gmail)

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I use Google Apps for my business. I route emails from my GApps email address to my personal email account on Gmail by way of setting the personal account to check and receive email from the GApps address.

However, there are rare occasions where an email that is sent to me never reaches either of the channels: I don't see them in my personal email address, and I don't see them in GApps email address. I've checked the spam folder for both and they're not there. The senders know for a fact that they've sent it, and this is not an isolated case.

I've double checked the MX settings and all is properly set up. I also have a catch-all forwarding in case the senders have misspelled my email address.

Is there something I can do to resolve this?

Is there a better way of receiving my work emails within my personal account?

Comment: How are you "setting the personal account to check and receive email from the gapps address"? POP3, IMAP?

Comment: It's POP3 since that is the only option under Settings > Accounts and Import > Check mail from other accounts (using POP3).

Comment: Google supports multiple sign in. I keep work and personal email separate this way. It's got several advantages. Many mobile apps support multiple gmail accounts, too.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers a troubleshooter for this cases.

From [An incoming message was delayed or hasn’t arrived](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2935079?hl=en).

> There are a number of reasons why messages may not arrive in your
>   inbox. To help you investigate what happened to your message, we'll
>   walk you through a step-by-step process to eliminate possible causes
>   of your missing messages.
>
> - Step 1: Search all messages
> - Step 2: Check All Mail, Spam, and Trash
> - Step 3: Check your forwarding and POP/IMAP settings
> - Step 4: Check your filters
> - Step 5: Check your Accounts settings

Follow the above link to see the detailed instructions for each step.

Answer (score 0):

If the message wasn't received by Google's servers, there is no way it can be delivered to your consumer Gmail account.

Start by using the email log search within your Google Apps account to find additional details on what happened to these 'missing' messages.

[About Email Log Search](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578?hl=en)
[Find messages with Email Log Search](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2618874?hl=en)

An alternative method that avoids forwarding mail is to give your consumer Gmail account delegated access to your Google Apps account. [Set up mail delegation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

There can be many reasons behind your Gmail like:

1. Check Gmail storage
2. You Should delete Email Filters
3. Disable Email Forwarding
4. Disable Firewalls
5. Check Gmail Service is down or not
6. Emails are not going to another folder like a spam folder
7. Disable your Antivirus Program

I wrote a full article on [Gmail not receiving emails](https://contactgmail.us/gmail-is-not-receiving-emails-what-to-do/) if you want to know full steps to resolve it then you can check.